# separating transition for hover and non-hover state

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-class

Here's a sample `div`-

```js
$("div").css("opacity","1");
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s 2.7s ease;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Initially I saw div's `transition` property overruling its `hover` transition (which it inherits from `body`) but I got it to work by specifying it separately for `:hover` state.
Now although it changes its color when hovered in no delay but when the mouse leaves, it takes `2.7s` to revert. Even the keyword `!important` has no impact.
What's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question correctly. But is this what you are looking for?

```js
$("div").css("opacity","1");
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: no. I corrected the line "although..." please read it again. The start of ````hover```` transition takes no time (as wanted) but the mouseleave event takes ````2.7s```` to take place. ````2.7s```` is the delay-time for ````div````'s non-hover state.

Comment: @Sapinder so when you hover onto the div you want it to take no time to transition? But when you move the mouse away (no longer hovering over the div) you want it to have a transition delay for the `background-color`?

Comment: no. I want hover transition just as simple as changing color with no delay. but something's causing it to delay the ````mouseleave```` transition back to original color. that's the ````2.7s```` i don't want.

Comment: @Sapinder Ok, so i've edited my answer, still think i'm not following though... You can remove the `transition` which causes the delay in the first place from either the `div` to prevent delay when moving the mouse away or from `div:hover` when moving the mouse over.

Comment: I wouldn't have used it if I didn't want to. I want some solution to set ````div````'s hover and non-hover transitions to separate delays.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `transition` property and try it once.

Try this link :

https://codepen.io/sateesh-gollapudi/pen/RwrPWLY?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 2.7s from the transition of div.

Change

`transition: all 0.2s 2.7s ease;`

to

`transition: all 0.2s ease;`

```js
$("div").css("opacity","1");
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease; /* Remove 2.7s */
}
div:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers shared already here with delay and without delay to avoid 2.7 seconds of delay. Question is still not very clear.

Here are transition properties which you are using as shorthand with 'transition: ' -

- transition-property
- transition-duration
- transition-timing-function
- transition-delay

transition: property duration timing-function delay|initial|inherit;

Use values accordingly to get desired result.